# Customized Toast or something else?

Tags: android

Sorry for my bad english.
I need help.

[image with view component](http://habrastorage.org/storage2/605/02c/601/60502c60140c90bcd61829a1cdee9af8.png)

What is the element with "Drag apps to your ..." text on Adroid emulator? Customized Toast or ... what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple view *(RelativeLayout or something similar)* within the RemoteViews of the widget.